# I am trying to get the average of a certain student but it adds all the the values

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to get the average of a certain student but it adds all the the values. this is the output program

```
        CMPE 325 Student Record Holder System
       --------------------------------
       1.Add Student
       2.View Records
       3.Update Students
       4.Get Average
       5.Exit
        --------------------------------
      Enter your choice: 1
        How many Students you want to input?: 
        2
        Student[1]Enter
        Id Number: 1
        First Name: Erwin
        Middle Name: asdasdas
        Last Name: sadasdas
        Degree: asdasdas
        Year Level: 1
        Student[2]Enter
        Id Number: 2
        First Name: INK
        Middle Name: asdasd
        Last Name: asdas
        Degree: sadas
        Year Level: 3
        CMPE 325 Student Record Holder System
        --------------------------------
        1.Add Student
        2.View Records
        3.Update Students
        4.Get Average
        5.Exit
        --------------------------------
        Enter your choice: 3
        Enter Id Number: 1
         ----------------Student Info-------------- 
        Id Number: 1
        Name:Erwin asdasdas sadasdas
        Degree and Year: asdasdas-1
        The number of Subjects: 
        3
        Name of Course: Law
        Enter Grade: 3
        Name of Course: Laww2
        Enter Grade: 1
        Name of Course: Law4
        Enter Grade: 2
        Enter another subject and grade? [Y]or[N]n
        CMPE 325 Student Record Holder System
        --------------------------------
        1.Add Student
        2.View Records
        3.Update Students
        4.Get Average
        5.Exit
        -------------------------------
        Enter your choice: 3
        Enter Id Number: 2
         ----------------Student Info-------------- 
        Id Number: 2
        Name:IDK asdasd asdas
        Degree and Year: sadas-3
        The number of Subjects: 
        2
        Name of Course: psych
        Enter Grade: 3
        Name of Course: egg
        Enter Grade: 2
        Enter another subject and grade? [Y]or[N]n
        CMPE 325 Student Record Holder System
        --------------------------------
        1.Add Student
        2.View Records
        3.Update Students
        4.Get Average
        5.Exit
        --------------------------------
        Enter your choice: 4
        ENTER ID NUMBER: 1
        SUM: 11.0
        AVERAGE: 2.2
```

this is my Tester

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RecHolder {

        static ArrayList<Rec> record = new ArrayList<Rec>();
        static ArrayList<Grade> records = new ArrayList<Grade>();


        public RecHolder() {
            menu();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        public static void menu() {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int choice;

            System.out.println("CMPE 325 Student Record Holder System");
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            System.out.println("1.Add Student");
            System.out.println("2.View Records");
            System.out.println("3.Update Students");
            System.out.println("4.Get Average");
            System.out.println("5.Exit");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
            choice = in.nextInt();

            switch (choice) 
            { 
            case 1: record(); break;
            case 2: display(); break;
            case 3: update(); break;
            case 4: average(); break;
            case 5:  break;

            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        public static void record() {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int total;


                System.out.println("How many Students you want to input?: ");
                total = in.nextInt();

                Rec[] student = new Rec[total];

                for (int index = 0; index < student.length; index++) {
                    student[index] = new Rec();

                    System.out.printf("Student[%d]", index + 1);
                    System.out.println("Enter");
                    in.nextLine();

                    System.out.print("Id Number: ");
                    student[index].setIdNumber(in.nextLine());

                    System.out.print("First Name: ");
                    student[index].setFirstName(in.nextLine());

                    System.out.print("Middle Name: ");
                    student[index].setMiddleName(in.nextLine());

                    System.out.print("Last Name: ");
                    student[index].setLastName(in.nextLine());

                    System.out.print("Degree: ");
                    student[index].setDegree(in.nextLine());

                    System.out.print("Year Level: ");
                    student[index].setYearLevel(in.nextInt());

                    record.add(student[index]);
                }

                menu();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        public static void displayall() {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            if(record.size() == 0)
            {
                System.out.print("Invalid\n");
                in.nextLine();
                menu();
            }
            else
            {
                if(records.size() == 1){
                    System.out.print("-------------The Record for all Student-----------");

                    for (int i = 0; i < record.size(); i++) {
                        System.out.printf("\nStudent[%d]", i + 1);
                        System.out.print("\nId Number: " + record.get(i).getIdNumber());
                        System.out.print("\nName: "+ record.get(i).getFirstName() + " "+ record.get(i).getMiddleName() + " "+ record.get(i).getLastName());
                        System.out.print("\nDegree and Year: "+ record.get(i).getDegree() + "-"+ record.get(i).getYearLevel()+"\n\n");

                    }
                    in.nextLine();
                    display();
                }

                else{
                    System.out.print("--------------The Record for all Student------------");

                    for (int i = 0; i < record.size(); i++) {
                        System.out.printf("\nStudent[%d]", i + 1);
                        System.out
                                .print("\nId Number: " + record.get(i).getIdNumber());
                        System.out.print("\nName: "+ record.get(i).getFirstName() + " "+ record.get(i).getMiddleName() + " "+ record.get(i).getLastName());
                        System.out.print("\nDegree and Year: "+ record.get(i).getDegree() + "-"+ record.get(i).getYearLevel()+"\n\n");

                    }

                //  for(int loopforSubjct = 0 ; loopforSubjct < records.size(); loopforSubjct++ )
                //  {
                //      System.out.printf("\nSubject: "+ records.get(loopforSubjct).getSubject()+" Grade: "+ records.get(loopforSubjct).getGrade());
                //  }

                    in.nextLine();
                }
            }
        display();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        public static void specific() {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            if(record.size() == 0)
            {
                System.out.print("Enter Data 1st\n");
                in.nextLine();
                menu();
            }
            else{

                String id = new String();
                System.out.print("Enter Id Number: ");
                id = in.nextLine();
                if(records.size()==1){
                    for (int loopforSpcfc = 0; loopforSpcfc < record.size(); loopforSpcfc++) {
                        if (id.equals(record.get(loopforSpcfc).getIdNumber())) {
                            System.out.printf("\n ----------------Student Exists-------------- ");
                            System.out.print("\nId Number: "+ record.get(loopforSpcfc).getIdNumber());
                            System.out.print("\nName:"+ record.get(loopforSpcfc).getFirstName() + " "+ record.get(loopforSpcfc).getMiddleName() + " "+ record.get(loopforSpcfc).getLastName());
                            System.out.print("\nDegree and Year: "+ record.get(loopforSpcfc).getDegree() + "-"+ record.get(loopforSpcfc).getYearLevel() + "\n\n");in.nextLine();

                        }
                     else
                        {   in.nextLine();
                            System.out.print("Student Number Invalid!\n");

                            menu();

                        }

                    }
                }

                else{
                for (int loopforSpcfc = 0; loopforSpcfc < record.size(); loopforSpcfc++) {
                        if (id.equals(record.get(loopforSpcfc).getIdNumber())) {
                            System.out.printf("\nStudent Exists");
                            System.out.print("\nId Number: "+ record.get(loopforSpcfc).getIdNumber());
                            System.out.print("\nName: "+ record.get(loopforSpcfc).getFirstName() + " "+ record.get(loopforSpcfc).getMiddleName() + " "+ record.get(loopforSpcfc).getLastName());
                            System.out.print("\nDegree and Year: "+ record.get(loopforSpcfc).getDegree() + "-"+ record.get(loopforSpcfc).getYearLevel() +"\n\n");
                            System.out.println();

                        }

                }
                for(int loopforSubjct = 0 ; loopforSubjct < records.size(); loopforSubjct++ )
                    {
                        System.out.printf("\nSubject: "+ records.get(loopforSubjct).getSubject()+" Grade: "+ records.get(loopforSubjct).getGrade());
                    }

                    in.nextLine();
                }

            }
            display();
        }

        public static void update(){
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            if(record.size() == 0)
            {
                System.out.print("Enter Data 1st\n");
                in.nextLine();
                menu();
            }
            else{
            String idnum = new String();
            char answer;
            in.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter Id Number: ");
            idnum = in.nextLine();
            int total;


                for (int loopforSpcfc = 0; loopforSpcfc < record.size(); loopforSpcfc++) {
                    if (idnum.equals(record.get(loopforSpcfc).getIdNumber())) {
                        System.out.printf("\n ----------------Student Info-------------- ");
                        System.out.print("\nId Number: "+ record.get(loopforSpcfc).getIdNumber());
                        System.out.print("\nName:"+ record.get(loopforSpcfc).getFirstName() + " "+ record.get(loopforSpcfc).getMiddleName() + " "+ record.get(loopforSpcfc).getLastName());
                        System.out.print("\nDegree and Year: "+ record.get(loopforSpcfc).getDegree() + "-"+ record.get(loopforSpcfc).getYearLevel() + "\n\n");in.nextLine();
                    }
                }

            for(int loop=0;loop<record.size();loop++){{
                    if(idnum.equals(record.get(loop).getIdNumber())){
                        System.out.println("The number of Sujects: ");
                        total = in.nextInt();
                        do{
                            Grade[] update = new Grade[total];
                        for(int indexupdater = 0;indexupdater<update.length;indexupdater++){
                            update[indexupdater] = new Grade();

                            in.nextLine();
                            System.out.print("Name of Course: ");
                            update[indexupdater].setSubject(in.nextLine());

                            System.out.print("Enter Grade: ");
                            update[indexupdater].setGrade(in.nextDouble());

                            records.add(update[indexupdater]);
                            }

                            System.out.print("Enter another subject and grade? [Y]or[N]");
                            String ans = in.next();
                            answer = ans.charAt(0);

                    }while(answer == 'y');

                }

            }
            }
            }
            menu();
        }




        public static void average()
        {

                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

                if(record.size() == 0)
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter Data 1st\n");
                    in.nextLine();
                    menu();
                }
                else{

                    double sum=0;
                    double average=0;
                    String ID = new String();

                    System.out.print("Enter An Valid Id Number: ");

                    for(int xx=0;xx<record.size();xx++){
                        if(ID.equals(record.get(xx).getIdNumber()))
                        {
                            for(int ind=0;ind<records.size();ind++)
                            {
                                    sum += records.get(ind).getGrade();
                            }
                            average=sum/records.size();
                            System.out.println(average);


                        System.out.print("SUM: "+sum);
                        System.out.print("\nAVERAGE: "+average);
        }
    }
                }
        }
        public static void display(){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            int choice;


                System.out.println("--------------------------------");
                System.out.println("1.View List");
                System.out.println("2.View Specific Record");
                System.out.println("3.Exit");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("--------------------------------");
                System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
                choice = input.nextInt();

                switch (choice) {

                case 1:
                    displayall();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    specific();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    menu();
                    break;

                }

        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
               new RecHolder();
            }
    }
```

This is for my Grades

    public class Grade {

```
            private String IDNumber;
            private String subject;
            private double grade;
            private double average;

            public Grade()
            {
                String IDNum;
                String sub;
                double grad;
                double ave;

            }

            public Grade(String IDNum,String sub,double grad,double ave)
            {
                this.IDNumber=IDNum;
                this.subject=sub;
                this.grade=grad;
                this.average=ave;

            }

            public void setSubject(String subject)
            {
                this.subject=subject;
            }
            public String getSubject()
            {
                return subject;
            }

            public void setGrade(double grade)
            {
                this.grade=grade;
            }
            public double getGrade()
            {
                return grade;
            }

            public String getIDNumber()
            {
                return IDNumber;
            }


}
```

for the StudntRecord

    public class Rec
    {
        private String IDNumber;
        private String firstName;
        private String middleName;
        private String lastName;
        private String degree;
        private int yearLevel;

```
    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        return ("ID Number: "+this.getIdNumber()+
                    "\nName: "+ this.getFirstName()+
                    " "+ this.getMiddleName()+
                    " "+ this.getLastName()+
                    "\nDegree and YearLevel: "+ this.getDegree() +
                    " - " + this.getYearLevel());
    }

    public Rec()
    {
        String IDNum;
        String fName;
        String mName;
        String lName;
        String deg;
        int level;  
    }

    public Rec(String IDNum, String fName, String mName, String lName, String deg,int level )
    {
        this.IDNumber=IDNum;
        this.firstName=fName;
        this.middleName=mName;
        this.lastName=lName;
        this.degree=deg;
        this.yearLevel=level;
    }

    public void setIdNumber(String IDNumber)
    {
        this.IDNumber = IDNumber;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName=firstName;
    }

    public void setMiddleName(String middleName)
    {
        this.middleName=middleName;
    }


    public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName=lastName;
    }


    public void setDegree(String degree)
    {
        this.degree=degree;
    }


    public void setYearLevel(int yearLevel)
    {
        this.yearLevel=yearLevel;
    }

    public String getIdNumber()
    {
        return IDNumber;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }


    public String getMiddleName()
    {
        return middleName;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getDegree()
    {
        return degree;
    }

    public int getYearLevel()
    {
        return yearLevel;
    }



}
```

Comment: Sorry for the Wrong FORMAT.:(

Comment: What is the input, what is the output, example please?

Comment: @user3145523 why did you undo my edit? I corrected the display so that your question is legible...

Comment: @atk  done a nice edit on your post, Why you reverted it back ?

Comment: sorry im reverting it ryt now

Comment: Calculate the "average=sum/records.size();" outside the for loop

Comment: I already did revert to what @atk did.

Comment: @AliGajani can i send it to you directly? its hard to post here.:(

Comment: @AliGajani. thank you for formating

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you calculate the average AFTER everything is added into the sum? 
You should calculate average outside the for loop.

Comment: its still adding all the grades

Comment: @SrinathGanesh

want do you mean? I still cant get it.

Comment: @SrinathGanesh woulld u mind helping me?? 
it still add all even i moved it out to the loop

Comment: @SrinathGanesh

ive reverted the code now.. Im still stuck with this.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int ind=0;ind<records.size();ind++)
{
   sum += records.get(ind).getGrade();

}
average=sum/records.size();
System.out.println(average);
```

Average needs to be calculated after the entire for loop adds things up, Just as Prasad said before.

Comment: @user3145523 above code is what i meant , i had just posted the format thanks to snocavotia he got you the whole code

Comment: @snocovatia

for(int ind=0;ind<records.size();ind++)
{
   sum += records.get(int).getGrade();

}
average=sum/records.size();
System.out.println(average);

is this an int?

Comment: No, That was a typ0 Refresh your browser. I edited that 5 seconds after I posted it.

Comment: it still adds the whole numbers inputed

Comment: Then, records.size() is evaulating to 1. Try printing it out. Thats why.

Comment: i want that method to only calculate the a certain number.. Look the output above. it calculated all my input and get its average i need help with that.

Comment: @can i contact u through any other means? ill gve u the code if u want. this is the last error i have.:( and today is the deadline.

Comment: @where will i post it? here??

Answer (score 1):

**code is written based to complete ASSUMPTIONS since the original poster @user3145523 has not posted his complete source code when i am posting this**

```
    String ID = "fillit";

// fetch grade list
for(ArrayList gradeList2 : records.get(ID).grade) 
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    double average = 0.0;

    // cal values for all grades
    for(int gradeValue : gradeList2)
    {
        sum = sum + gradeValue;
    }

    // cal average of sum
        average = sum / gradeList2.count();
}

System.out.print("SUM: "+sum);
System.out.print("\nAVERAGE: "+average);
```

---

> Assumptions

1. records is assumed to be a main ArrayList (the question is TAGGED arraylist)
2. the records is assumed to contain another ArrayList called grades (in the first post the user seems to have a dynamic way to allocate grade count and a simple array for grade seems unlikely )
3. assumed ArrayList grades is assumed to contain integer-int elements
4. **major assumption** average of grades of one student is computed . reason -> original poster said

> i want that method to only calculate the a certain number.. Look the output above. it calculated all my input and get its average i need help with that

---

---

---

Asking user if this is fine in post (got no other option to contact)

is this fine ? ? ?

output pasted->

> ### CMPE 325 Student Record Holder System
>
> 1.Add Student
>   2.View Records
>   3.Update Students
>   4.Get Average
>   5.Exit
>
> -------------------------------- Enter your choice: 1 How many Students you want to input?:  2 Student[1]Enter Id Number: 1 First
>   Name: a Middle Name: b Last Name: c Degree: 1 Year Level: 1
>   Student[2]Enter Id Number: 2 First Name: d Middle Name: e Last Name: f
>
> ### Degree: 1 Year Level: 1 CMPE 325 Student Record Holder System
>
> 1.Add Student
>   2.View Records
>   3.Update Students
>   4.Get Average
>   5.Exit
>
> -------------------------------- Enter your choice: 3
>
> Enter Id Number: 1
>
> ----------------Student Info--------------  Id Number: 1 Name:a b c
>   Degree and Year: 1-1
>
> The number of Sujects:  2 Name of Course: aa Enter Grade: 2 Name of
>   Course: bb Enter Grade: 6 Enter another subject and grade? [Y]or[N]n
>
> ### CMPE 325 Student Record Holder System
>
> 1.Add Student
>   2.View Records
>   3.Update Students
>   4.Get Average
>   5.Exit
>
> -------------------------------- Enter your choice: 3
>
> Enter Id Number: 2
>
> ----------------Student Info--------------  Id Number: 2 Name:d e f
>   Degree and Year: 1-1
>
> The number of Sujects:  2 Name of Course: cc Enter Grade: 5 Name of
>   Course: dd Enter Grade: 7 Enter another subject and grade? [Y]or[N]n
>
> ### CMPE 325 Student Record Holder System
>
> 1.Add Student
>   2.View Records
>   3.Update Students
>   4.Get Average
>   5.Exit
>
> -------------------------------- Enter your choice: 4 Enter An Valid Id Number: 1 SUM: 8.0 AVERAGE: 2.0

---

CODE -> includes originally posted codes too **(adding on user... request)**

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RecHolder {

    static ArrayList<Rec> record = new ArrayList<Rec>();
    static ArrayList<Grade> records = new ArrayList<Grade>();

    public RecHolder() {
        menu();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void menu() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice;

        System.out.println("CMPE 325 Student Record Holder System");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println("1.Add Student");
        System.out.println("2.View Records");
        System.out.println("3.Update Students");
        System.out.println("4.Get Average");
        System.out.println("5.Exit");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
        choice = in.nextInt();

        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            record();
            break;
        case 2:
            display();
            break;
        case 3:
            update();
            break;
        case 4:
            average();
            break;
        case 5:
            break;

        }
    }

    public static void record() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int total;

        System.out.println("How many Students you want to input?: ");
        total = in.nextInt();

        Rec[] student = new Rec[total];

        for (int index = 0; index < student.length; index++) {
            student[index] = new Rec();

            System.out.printf("Student[%d]", index + 1);
            System.out.println("Enter");
            in.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Id Number: ");
            student[index].setIdNumber(in.nextLine());

            System.out.print("First Name: ");
            student[index].setFirstName(in.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Middle Name: ");
            student[index].setMiddleName(in.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Last Name: ");
            student[index].setLastName(in.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Degree: ");
            student[index].setDegree(in.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Year Level: ");
            student[index].setYearLevel(in.nextInt());

            record.add(student[index]);
        }

        menu();
    }

    public static void displayall() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (record.size() == 0) {
            System.out.print("Invalid\n");
            in.nextLine();
            menu();
        } else {
            if (records.size() == 1) {
                System.out
                        .print("-------------The Record for all Student-----------");

                for (int i = 0; i < record.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.printf("\nStudent[%d]", i + 1);
                    System.out.print("\nId Number: "
                            + record.get(i).getIdNumber());
                    System.out.print("\nName: " + record.get(i).getFirstName()
                            + " " + record.get(i).getMiddleName() + " "
                            + record.get(i).getLastName());
                    System.out.print("\nDegree and Year: "
                            + record.get(i).getDegree() + "-"
                            + record.get(i).getYearLevel() + "\n\n");

                }
                in.nextLine();
                display();
            }

            else {
                System.out
                        .print("--------------The Record for all Student------------");

                for (int i = 0; i < record.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.printf("\nStudent[%d]", i + 1);
                    System.out.print("\nId Number: "
                            + record.get(i).getIdNumber());
                    System.out.print("\nName: " + record.get(i).getFirstName()
                            + " " + record.get(i).getMiddleName() + " "
                            + record.get(i).getLastName());
                    System.out.print("\nDegree and Year: "
                            + record.get(i).getDegree() + "-"
                            + record.get(i).getYearLevel() + "\n\n");

                }

                // for(int loopforSubjct = 0 ; loopforSubjct < records.size();
                // loopforSubjct++ )
                // {
                // System.out.printf("\nSubject: "+
                // records.get(loopforSubjct).getSubject()+" Grade: "+
                // records.get(loopforSubjct).getGrade());
                // }

                in.nextLine();
            }
        }
        display();
    }

    public static void specific() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (record.size() == 0) {
            System.out.print("Enter Data 1st\n");
            in.nextLine();
            menu();
        } else {

            String id = new String();
            System.out.print("Enter Id Number: ");
            id = in.nextLine();
            if (records.size() == 1) {
                for (int loopforSpcfc = 0; loopforSpcfc < record.size(); loopforSpcfc++) {
                    if (id.equals(record.get(loopforSpcfc).getIdNumber())) {
                        System.out
                                .printf("\n ----------------Student Exists-------------- ");
                        System.out.print("\nId Number: "
                                + record.get(loopforSpcfc).getIdNumber());
                        System.out.print("\nName:"
                                + record.get(loopforSpcfc).getFirstName() + " "
                                + record.get(loopforSpcfc).getMiddleName()
                                + " " + record.get(loopforSpcfc).getLastName());
                        System.out.print("\nDegree and Year: "
                                + record.get(loopforSpcfc).getDegree() + "-"
                                + record.get(loopforSpcfc).getYearLevel()
                                + "\n\n");
                        in.nextLine();

                    } else {
                        in.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Student Number Invalid!\n");

                        menu();

                    }

                }
            }

            else {
                for (int loopforSpcfc = 0; loopforSpcfc < record.size(); loopforSpcfc++) {
                    if (id.equals(record.get(loopforSpcfc).getIdNumber())) {
                        System.out.printf("\nStudent Exists");
                        System.out.print("\nId Number: "
                                + record.get(loopforSpcfc).getIdNumber());
                        System.out.print("\nName: "
                                + record.get(loopforSpcfc).getFirstName() + " "
                                + record.get(loopforSpcfc).getMiddleName()
                                + " " + record.get(loopforSpcfc).getLastName());
                        System.out.print("\nDegree and Year: "
                                + record.get(loopforSpcfc).getDegree() + "-"
                                + record.get(loopforSpcfc).getYearLevel()
                                + "\n\n");
                        System.out.println();

                    }

                }
                for (int loopforSubjct = 0; loopforSubjct < records.size(); loopforSubjct++) {
                    System.out.printf("\nSubject: "
                            + records.get(loopforSubjct).getSubject()
                            + " Grade: "
                            + records.get(loopforSubjct).getGrade());
                }

                in.nextLine();
            }

        }
        display();
    }

    public static void update() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (record.size() == 0) {
            System.out.print("Enter Data 1st\n");
            in.nextLine();
            menu();
        } else {
            String idnum = new String();
            char answer;
            in.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter Id Number: ");
            idnum = in.nextLine();
            int total;

            for (int loopforSpcfc = 0; loopforSpcfc < record.size(); loopforSpcfc++) {
                if (idnum.equals(record.get(loopforSpcfc).getIdNumber())) {
                    System.out
                            .printf("\n ----------------Student Info-------------- ");
                    System.out.print("\nId Number: "
                            + record.get(loopforSpcfc).getIdNumber());
                    System.out.print("\nName:"
                            + record.get(loopforSpcfc).getFirstName() + " "
                            + record.get(loopforSpcfc).getMiddleName() + " "
                            + record.get(loopforSpcfc).getLastName());
                    System.out.print("\nDegree and Year: "
                            + record.get(loopforSpcfc).getDegree() + "-"
                            + record.get(loopforSpcfc).getYearLevel() + "\n\n");
                    in.nextLine();
                }
            }

            for (int loop = 0; loop < record.size(); loop++) {
                {
                    if (idnum.equals(record.get(loop).getIdNumber())) {
                        System.out.println("The number of Sujects: ");
                        total = in.nextInt();
                        do {
                            Grade[] update = new Grade[total];
                            for (int indexupdater = 0; indexupdater < update.length; indexupdater++) {
                                update[indexupdater] = new Grade();

                                // set ID... String
                                update[indexupdater].setIDNumber(idnum);

                                in.nextLine();
                                System.out.print("Name of Course: ");
                                update[indexupdater].setSubject(in.nextLine());

                                System.out.print("Enter Grade: ");
                                update[indexupdater].setGrade(in.nextDouble());

                                records.add(update[indexupdater]);
                            }

                            System.out
                                    .print("Enter another subject and grade? [Y]or[N]");
                            String ans = in.next();
                            answer = ans.charAt(0);

                        } while (answer == 'y');

                    }

                }
            }
        }
        menu();
    }

    public static void average() {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        if (record.size() == 0) {
            System.out.print("Enter Data 1st\n");
            in.nextLine();
            menu();
        } else {

            double sum = 0;
            double average = 0;
            String ID = new String();

            System.out.print("Enter An Valid Id Number: ");
            ID = in.nextLine();

            for (Rec rec : record) {
                if (rec.getIdNumber().equals(ID)) {

                    for (Grade grade : records) {
                        if (grade.getIDNumber().equals(ID)) {
                            // System.out.println(grade.getIDNumber());
                            sum = sum + grade.getGrade();
                        }
                    } // end loop-grade

                    average = sum / records.size();

                } // end if
            } // end loop-rec

            System.out.print("SUM: " + sum);
            System.out.print("\nAVERAGE: " + average);
        }
    }

    public static void display() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int choice;

        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println("1.View List");
        System.out.println("2.View Specific Record");
        System.out.println("3.Exit");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
        choice = input.nextInt();

        switch (choice) {

        case 1:
            displayall();
            break;
        case 2:
            specific();
            break;
        case 3:
            menu();
            break;

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RecHolder();
    }
}
```

---

```
    class Grade {

    private String IDNumber;
    private String subject;
    private double grade;
    private double average;

    public Grade() {
        String IDNum;
        String sub;
        double grad;
        double ave;

    }

    public Grade(String IDNum, String sub, double grad, double ave) {
        this.IDNumber = IDNum;
        this.subject = sub;
        this.grade = grad;
        this.average = ave;

    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setGrade(double grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public double getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public String getIDNumber() {
        return IDNumber;
    }

    public void setIDNumber(String ID) {
        this.IDNumber = ID;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Rec {
    private String IDNumber;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    private String degree;
    private int yearLevel;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ("ID Number: " + this.getIdNumber() + "\nName: "
                + this.getFirstName() + " " + this.getMiddleName() + " "
                + this.getLastName() + "\nDegree and YearLevel: "
                + this.getDegree() + " - " + this.getYearLevel());
    }

    public Rec() {
        String IDNum;
        String fName;
        String mName;
        String lName;
        String deg;
        int level;
    }

    public Rec(String IDNum, String fName, String mName, String lName,
            String deg, int level) {
        this.IDNumber = IDNum;
        this.firstName = fName;
        this.middleName = mName;
        this.lastName = lName;
        this.degree = deg;
        this.yearLevel = level;
    }

    public void setIdNumber(String IDNumber) {
        this.IDNumber = IDNumber;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setDegree(String degree) {
        this.degree = degree;
    }

    public void setYearLevel(int yearLevel) {
        this.yearLevel = yearLevel;
    }

    public String getIdNumber() {
        return IDNumber;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getDegree() {
        return degree;
    }

    public int getYearLevel() {
        return yearLevel;
    }

}
```

Comment: This deserves more upvotes. Kudos for the efforts Srinath. It must be above all answers.

Comment: Nice one. Sorry i ddnt post my whole code above im stuck with the format thing. It says i must add more comment

i now posted my codes above

Comment: ill try out and get back to you

Comment: @user3145523 kindly view the last part of the post

Comment: @SrinathGanesh

okay.. I'll go dig in for more reference and other alternatives
thank you so much.:)

Comment: @SrinathGanesh.. Can i see the whole code??
the format was not that good.:(

Comment: Can u give me the whole method?
or the whole code
that u edited that works..My codes are in chaos now.:(

Comment: @user3145523 what changes do you need (what bugs are left)

Comment: @user3145523 any more ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the whole code so that we can understand the structure. How is the 'records' maintained and all.

With the available code, what i understand is :

```
if(ID.equals(record.get(xx).getIdNumber()))
```

This will check the condition and enter the loop.
But once entered,

```
for(int ind=0;ind<records.size();ind++)
{
sum += records.get(ind).getGrade();
average=sum/records.size();
}
```

Here, id is not considered. All the grades are summed up and average is calculated.
Your code structure may not be having link between id and the corresponding records or you are not considering the grades for the id through proper logic.

The whole code structure is required to help you further.

Comment: i ve posted the whole code now.
im sorry for the late reply i was experimenting my whole program

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
ID = in.nextLine();
for (int ind = 0; ind < records.size(); ind++) {
if (ID.equals(record.get(ind).getIdNumber())) {
 sum += records.get(ind).getGrade();
}
  }
System.out.print("SUM: " + sum);
 average = sum / records.size();
 System.out.print("\nAVERAGE: " + average);
```